# hql request: order list result by manytomany collection property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a hql request which looks like:

```
select Distinct prof 
from Professor as prof 
left join fetch prof.students as stud
```

Professor and Student are in a manytomany relation.
I would like to order prof list by student's name.

I tried :

```
select Distinct prof
from Professor as prof
left join fetch prof.students as stud
order by prof.students.name
```

I got the error: 
SEVERE: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection

I also tried:

```
select Distinct prof
from Professor as prof
left join fetch prof.students as stud
order by stud.name
```

I got the error:
SEVERE: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query;

Is my order by clause possible? Or the hibernate mapping doesn't allow such request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `Distinct` keyword from your query.  Then, if you need to eliminate duplicates, use a ResultTransformer to consolidate the result set for you.

```
String hql = "select prof from Professor as prof left join fetch prof.students as stud order by stud.name"; 
Query query = session.createQuery(hql)
                     .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```